# How to 'login' to secure website using python for a webpage that uses java and does not have any real source when viewing page source

Tags: python, web

I would like to make a script to login into my bank and download the latest transactions but I am stumped at the login page as it seems to be dynamically created each time and very little helpful information in the page source.  I am new to using Python for this task and would appreciate any direction on how to do this.  I get that most websites login would use some form of post to send the username and password but my bank has done something crazy to be secure which I guess is fine but it is not helping my cause....

This is the login page I would like to login into using Python.

https://www.txn.banking.pcfinancial.ca/ebm-resources/public/client/web/index.html#/signon

Comment: I'd recommend using Selenium here

Comment: if mint.com supports your bank you can easily get your banking data ... otherwise you will be looking at a painful job using ghost.js or selenium or something similar ... and its gonna be painful .... did I mention its gonna really suck doing it that way ... (and you might be violating some TOS)

Comment: looks like that login form sends requests to `https://www.txn.banking.pcfinancial.ca/ebm-anp/api/v1/json/sessions` if you feel like poking around.

Comment: @castis which sounds like an api :P ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley yes I had considered using mint.com but it actually violates the TOS with PC Financial...that fact is anyone in canada using mint.com with canadian chartered bank is in violation of their banks TOS as I understand it as no canadian banks have come on board to creating read only access much like US banks have.  I did not feel comfortable and would rather keep my credentials safe under my own watch but I'm looking at ways I can automate some of the daily logging and monitoring of the transactions.  I know it will be painful but it might serve as a good learning exercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after a bit more web scraping experience under my belt I have revisited this challenge and have come up with a solution using Selenium web driver with firefox. It works quite well, however there definitely could be improvements made like replacing the hard waits for something more elegant to get Selenium to wait for the page to reload but it gives a good idea to anyone else that might be interested in automating the downloading and loading of their banking information from PC Financial (which is Simplii now).  I do this as I import this information into Beancount/fava to monitor my finances closely.

here is my current working script...it will download all transactions since last download for select accounts that match on last 4 digits and rename the downloaded file using the last 4 digits of the account and the current date.

```
# import libraries
import re

from contextlib import closing
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox # pip install selenium
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import time
import os
from datetime import datetime

current_date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

# specify the url
urlpage = 'https://online.simplii.com/ebm-resources/public/client/web/index.html#/signon' 
print(urlpage)

dl_dir = "/home/user/bank_statements"
profile = FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("browser.download.panel.shown", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile","text/csv")
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/csv")
profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", dl_dir)

# list of last 4 digits of account numbers to download statements for
account_filter = ['1234','4321','9999']

with closing(Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)) as driver:
    driver.get(urlpage)
    time.sleep(7)

    # enter card number
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='cardNumber']").send_keys('123456789')
    # enter online banking passward
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='password']").send_keys('yourpassword')
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[text()='Sign In']").click()

    time.sleep(5)

    driver.find_element_by_link_text('Download Transactions').click()
    time.sleep(2)

    act_section = driver.find_element_by_class_name('account-section')
    act_select = Select(act_section.find_element_by_tag_name('select'))
    options = act_select.options
    for act in range(1, len(options)-1):
        # extract last 4-digits of account number
        last4_search = re.search(r'.+\(\d{6}(\d{4})\)\s+\$', options[act].text)
        if last4_search:
            last4 = last4_search.group(1)
            if last4 in account_filter:
                print('downloading transactions for: ...' + last4)
                act_select.select_by_index(act)
                last_dl = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='radio'][@value='LAST_DOWNLOAD']/ancestor::ui-radiobutton")
                result = last_dl.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='radio'][@value='LAST_DOWNLOAD']").is_selected()
                if result == False:
                    last_dl.click()
                format_section = driver.find_element_by_class_name('format-section')
                format_select = Select(format_section.find_element_by_tag_name('select'))
                format_select.select_by_index(3)

                # initiate download
                driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[text()='Download Transactions']").click()
                time.sleep(10)

                # rename file
                if os.path.isfile(dl_dir + '/SIMPLII.csv'):
                    os.rename(dl_dir + '/SIMPLII.csv', dl_dir + '_'.join(['/SIMPLII',last4,current_date,'.csv']))
```